# how receive the last sequence emission when calling rx.Observable.sample()?

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java

I am reading a file from a remote url and using RxJava to report on the download progress. The file writer Observable emits a sequence of DownloadProgress objects. Because a lot of items are being emitted, I am using Observable.sample() to manage backpressure. This works very well - UI updates come at a constant rate and there are no backpressure issues, but the last progress update is almost always skipped.

I would like to receive the last item in the Observable sequence so I can update the UI with the final progress. What's the best way to ensure that the last item from the Observable sequence is always emitted?

```
Observable<Response> fileReader =
        Rx.okHttpGetRequest(url);
OkHttpResponseWriter fileWriter =
        Rx.okHttpResponseWriter(outFile);

Subscription subscription = fileReader.flatMap(fileWriter)
        .sample(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<DownloadProgress>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {}
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {}
            @Override
            public void onNext(DownloadProgress progress) {
                // I want to receive an update every one second
                // I also want to always receive the last progress update
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just handle it in `onCompleted`? If I understood correctly, you need this last update to handle finished download?

Comment: The `DownloadProgress` object contains information that I would like to expose to the subscriber, including the total bytes read from the file. `onCompleted` notifies the subscriber that the sequence has completed, but does not re-emit the last item in the sequence. Assume that it is critical to read the data from that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, using `buffer` instead of `sample`, will get you an emission with the "extra" ones at the end. I'd suggest this instead, that way you don't lose any composability or introduce headaches for future developers (including future you).

```
private Subscriber<List<Integer>> loggingSubscriber2 = new SimpleSubscriber<List<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(List<Integer> integers) {
        Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(integers.get(integers.size() - 1)));
    }
};

private void startObservableTests() {
    Observable<Integer> fileObserver = Observable.create(
            new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                        subscriber.onNext(i);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    fileObserver.buffer(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe(loggingSubscriber2);
}
```

Comment: This is a very clever solution that I never would have thought of. I posted a fancier version that uses `window` instead of `buffer` but it's essentially the same technique.

Answer (score 2):

This is where I ended up:

```
private void startObservableTests() {

    Observable<Integer> fileObserver = Observable.create(
            new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                        subscriber.onNext(i);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());


    fileObserver.sample(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe(new SuperSubscriber(fileObserver));
}

private class SuperSubscriber extends Subscriber<Integer> {

    Observable obs;

    public SuperSubscriber(Observable<Integer> fileObserver) {
        obs = fileObserver;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        obs.last().subscribe(new SimpleSubscriber<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer o) {
                Log.v(TAG, "final value was " + o);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer o) {
        Log.v(TAG, "got a " + o);
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
10-01 15:18:36.893 V/TAG  (26129): got a 5
10-01 15:18:38.214 V/TAG  (26129): final value was 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the excellent solution posted by @Travis, here is the final code I ended up with. Instead of `buffer`, I used `window` in combination with `switchOnNext` to do some further processing:

```
Observable<Response> fileReader =
    Rx.okHttpGetRequest(fileInfo.getUrl());
OkHttpResponseWriter fileWriter =
    Rx.okHttpResponseWriter(outFile, totalBytesRead);
Subscription subscription = Observable.switchOnNext(fileReader
        .flatMap(fileWriter)
        .window(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<DownloadProgress>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {}
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {}
            @Override
            public void onNext(DownloadProgress progress) {
                // always emits the most recent DownloadProgress, even the last one!
            }
});
```

Explanation:

- `fileReader` takes a URL, creates an HTTP request and emits a `Response`
- `fileReader.flatMap(fileWriter)` takes the `Response` and writes the byte stream to disk, emitting a sequence of `DownloadProgress` objects
- `window(1, TimeUnit.Seconds)` emits a `List<DownloadProgress>` objects each second, then packages and re-emits them as an `Observable<DownloadProgress>`
- `Observable.switchOnNext()` takes the most recently emitted `Observable<DownloadProgress>` and emits the last `DownloadProgress` object in the sequence

Comment: I get a MissingBackpressureException